# Where in CentOS 7 should I install Ruby?

Tags: centos, software-installation, git, ruby

I am installing `Ruby` and `rbenv` on a CentOS 7 by following [the instructions in this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-centos-7), with modifications.  One of the recommended lines of code is `cd` followed by `git clone` commands.  I assume that the `cd` should be `cd /path_to_destination_of_cloned_code`, **so where on a CentOS 7 file system should I install the rbenv and ruby git cloned code?**

Also, any other suggested changes to the code below would be much valued.  I have not yet run the code below, and am still planning an optimal install methodology.

---

**SUMMARY OF CODE MODIFIED FROM TUTORIAL:**

---

// Install the `rbenv` and `Ruby` dependencies with `yum` as `root`:

```
sudo yum install -y git-core zlib zlib-devel gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison curl sqlite-devel
```

// Switch to the user who will be using Ruby to run the following commands:
// 1.) Now we are ready to install rbenv into your home directory, and set the appropriate environment variables that will allow rbenv to the active version of Ruby:

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
exec $SHELL

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
exec $SHELL
```

// 2.) Determine which version of Ruby to install by visiting https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/  and then install it with these commands:

```
rbenv install -v 2.3.0  
rbenv global 2.3.0
```

// 3.) Verify that Ruby was installed properly with this command:

```
ruby -v
```

// 4.) Disable Rubygems' generation of local documentation for each gem that you install with this command:

```
echo "gem: --no-document" > ~/.gemrc
```

// 5.) Install the bundler gem, to manage application dependencies:

```
gem install bundler
```

---

**NOTE:**

---

I found the following commands, which worked like a charm when run as a super user:

```
// the first line is supposed to be just dependencies, as follows:  
yum install -y git-core zlib zlib-devel gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison curl sqlite-devel  
yum install ruby ruby-devel rubygems //ruby-devel is required to add headers needed by some libraries
ruby -v  // confirm ruby is installed, and check version
```

Given that you can essentially just `yum install ruby` and let the distro manage all the behind the scenes, why would anyone both with the verbose approach from the tutorial above?

Comment: I don't know a thing about ruby, but my interpretation of the above steps is that it installs a local copy of whatever's in git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git into a non-root user's home directory. I'm assuming the tutorial itself assumed as much non-root activity as possible, otherwise root or the sysadmin could just [install ruby via RPM](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#yum)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you.  Your non-sudoer theory makes sense.  When you were writing that, I was trying what I added to the end of the OP around the same time, which is just slightly more code.

Comment: Local installs rarely make sense, but as in many cases, this does not stop people from recommending them. Don't treat random web tutorials as gospel. Also, a better place to comment on the article would be in the article comments.